# Conditional expectation with respect to paths of a Markov jump process

Tags: pr.probability, markov-chains, statistical-physics

I'm having some trouble detangeling how the conditional expectation in equation (2.13) in the article https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9811220 (Lebowitz, Spohn) is defined.

The context is as follows: they consider a continuous time Markov jump process $(\sigma_s)$, with transition rate matrix $k(\sigma,\sigma')$, and define the action functional
$$
W(t,\{\sigma_s,0\leq s \leq t\})=\int_0^t\sum_{\sigma,\sigma'}w_{\sigma,\sigma'}(s)ds
$$
where $w_{\sigma,\sigma'}(s)$ is a sequence of $\delta$-functions located at the times $\sigma_s$ performs a jump from $\sigma$ to $\sigma'$, weighted by $w(\sigma,\sigma')=\ln k(\sigma,\sigma')-\ln k(\sigma',\sigma)$. I.e., if $(\sigma_s)$ is a path that visits $\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n$ in succession,
$$
W(t,\{\sigma_s,0\leq s\leq t\})=\ln\left[\frac{k(\sigma_1,\sigma_2)}{k(\sigma_2,\sigma_1)}\cdots\frac{k(\sigma_{n-1},\sigma_n)}{k(\sigma_n,\sigma_{n-1})}\right]
$$

I am having trouble understanding how they define the expectation
$$
g(\sigma,t)=\mathbb{E}_{\sigma}\left[e^{-\lambda W(t)}\right]
$$
where $\mathbb{E}_{\sigma}$ is meant to denote that the expectation is conditional on $(\sigma_s)$ being in state $\sigma$ at time $t=0$.

It seems to me that this expectation is supposed to be taken over paths $(\sigma_s)$, although this intuition has led me nowhere in showing their subsequent result, which states that
$$
\frac{d}{dt}g(\sigma,t)=\sum_{\sigma'}\left[k(\sigma,\sigma')e^{-\lambda w(\sigma,\sigma')}g(\sigma',t)-k(\sigma,\sigma')g(\sigma,t)\right]
$$

Any light that could be shed on this would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: they do also assume that the distribution of $(\sigma_s)$ converges to a stationary measure $\mu_s(\sigma)$. I believe this is supposed to matter somehow.